# 10,000+ different files and I need to grab 4 of them every 5 seconds?

Tags: php, database, database-design, sqlite

I have a database of 10,000+ different files and I need to grab 4 random ones out of that database every 5 seconds.

I am wondering what are you suggestions for architect. I am thinking of using a flat file or maybe a sqlite? Doing this via mysql would be very very slow?

Comment: Why do you think MySQL will be very slow? 10K record table is considered "small" in MySQL

Comment: Are you looking to change the database that you say you already have?

Comment: Grabbing 4 random tables every 5 seconds on MySql is not exactly what I want to do on my rather poop mysql server. So I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: You say tables, but in your question you said files(making one think you store one file per row), and below you refer to rows.  A file, table, and row are all very different things.  While your implementation to solve your problem perhaps could use either, it is really important you define your problem more clearly.  You state that it is a database of "10,000+ different files".  How are you storing these files in your database currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a Generalized Approach
Running The `selectRandom()` procedure every 5seconds will be too messy. instead run `selectRandomGroups()` every 120 seconds.

`selectRandomGroups()` executes `selectRandom()` 120/5 times in every execution. and stores the resulting groups in some storage (cache).

next use `grabRandomGroup()` every 5 seconds that retrieves the last Group from the cache.and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the files into a directory with deterministic names (0.dat, 1.dat, etc) and read them directly.

The B-tree and caching in the file system will take care of the rest. This is EXACTLY what it was designed to do.

Comment: Okay, the only problem with that is, the actual database is over a million rows there are only specific ones I want to display. (Approved and only images). So I would much rather have maybe have a script run every 24 hours to grab the new data and write it somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, you stated 10,000+ files? Does that mean 10,000 files that map to some of your 1,000,000+ records? Or is it really 1,000,000+ files, most of which won't be a candidate for displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a very heavy relational DB background, my first reaction is not to recommend the "NoSQL" document type of database systems.  But in this case, it sounds like basically you will be needing one large hash table.  I would look at something like MongoDB or CouchDB.  You can see the differences here (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB,+CouchDB,+MySQL+Compare+Grid).

The other thing you might look at is storing this info in the "cloud" using Amazon S3 or something similar if you think you need to scale a lot soon and don't have the capacity inhouse.

Otherwise, the file system idea noted above would work also

Comment: ps  Are you storing links to the files or the files as blobs?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store links to the images instead of the entire image files? A query that returns 4 filenames every 5 seconds shouldn't put much if any load on the mysql server. Certainly less than installing and running another DBMS presumably on the same server.

Assuming that this is some type of website you could offload it to user machines by generating the random file names with javascript and then do whatever you needed to with the images.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your comments that your files are stored in the same table. Why would something like this be too slow?

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE approved = 1 AND type = image ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

And why would it be faster to run a script every 24 hours that fetches 69120 files and writes them to a directory or whatever? But sure, you could do that. Just change the limit in the above query.

Comment: BTW, the above applies even if the files are stored on disk and you just have filenames (links) in the table too.